# Up and Down rows from table

Tags: jquery, html-table, move

I have a table where I can select/deselect many rows. I want to move those rows up or down in the table. However when I move the rows they disappear and I don't know why. I think the problem is located on this precise line of code:

```
$(this).appendTo($(this).prev());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table1 tbody tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table2 tbody tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".down").click(function() {
    $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('class') == 'selected') {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).next());
      }
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".up").click(function() {
    $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('class') == 'selected') {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).prev());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected td {
  background: #ffffcf;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="up">UP</button>
<button type="button" class="down">DOWN</button>
<h2>Table1</h2>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Table2</h2>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>Row21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row26</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5jxvaw3d/

Comment: You haven't described the problem nor the behaviour you want to create, so it's not clear what you're asking. Also note that you don't need to repeat the document.ready handler; put the event handlers within a single one.

Comment: Are we required to guess what the nature of the problem is, or are you going to explain for us?

Comment: I edited my problem, sorry for not being clear

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/dkwvmrfg/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `appendTo()` to `insertBefore()` and `insertAfter()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table1 tbody tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table2 tbody tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".down").click(function() {
    $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('class') == 'selected') {
        $(this).insertAfter($(this).nextAll(':not(.selected)').eq(0));
      }
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".up").click(function() {
    $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('class') == 'selected') {
        $(this).insertBefore($(this).prevAll(':not(.selected)').eq(0));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="up">UP</button>
<button type="button" class="down">DOWN</button>
<h2>Table1</h2>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Table2</h2>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>Row21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row26</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**

Quick fix for problem of selected two next to each other

change this `$(this).insertBofer($(this).prev());` to `$(this).insertBefore($(this).prevAll(':not(.selected)').eq(0));`

(Updated snippet)

Comment: What If we've more than one row selected?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki What then?

Comment: Select row1 and row2 and click down or up ... nothing move

Comment: Yep, that's true, but that's a different problem. The logic is failing, because first row goes under second, and then second under first and thus nothing changes.

Comment: Yeah that's true because of the structure of the code, if you select 2 following rows  you can move down them, i will try to fix this !

Comment: @LucThilliez glad I could help. Don't forget to accept this answer and also give a plus one.